# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined mongoose Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to *get* and *remove* object from mongodb. But I am getting following error.

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I want to get object by Id  and Id in my Schema is just because I am trying out gRPC with nodejs and mongoDB, Without Database gRPC code was working fine but after connecting to database its throwing errors, when I tried to trace error only in nodejs got above mentioned error and test code is attached in last.

Note: Insert and List working fine.

Here is my mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const todoSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: "Enter title"
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: "Enter Description"
    },
    done: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    createdate: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('todo', todoSchema);
```

Here is my tododb code

```
var todoModel = require('./models/todo')

var Todo = class {

    constructor(payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    static list(callback) {
        todoModel.find({}, callback);
    }

    insert(callback) {
        new todoModel(this.payload).save(callback);
    }

    get(callback) {
        const condition = this.payload.condition;
        todoModel.find(condition). exec(callback)
    }

    delete(callback) {
        const condition = this.payload;
        todoModel.remove(condition, callback);
    }
};
module.exports = Todo;
```

Test Code is Here

```
var assert = {
    get: function (call,callback) {
        var payload = {
            condition: {
                id: call
            }
        };
        var t = new TodoDb(payload);


   t.get(callback);
    },
};


try {
    assert.get(40, callback);
    console.log('Passed.');
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

Note 2 : I am also beginner in JS and its tech

Answer (score 1):

In your test code you're executing:

```
assert.get(40);
```

the assert.get execute the following function with the parameter call = 40

```
function (call) {
    var payload = {
        condition: {
            id: call.request.id
        }
    };
    var t = new TodoDb(payload);


    t.get(callback);
}
```

So if call = 40 then what is the value of

> call.request.id

call = 40

call.request = 40.request = undefined

call.request.id = 40.request.id = undefined.id

Which give the error:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

---

It means you are trying to access the property id on an `undefined` or `null` object

Comment: Ok I edited it
id: call
So now it is like this
id:40
still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Here in this part of code :

```
var assert = {
    get: function (call) {
        var payload = {
            condition: {
                id: call.request.id
            }
        };
        var t = new TodoDb(payload);


   t.get(callback);
    },
};
```

You call `assert.get(40);` and the `call` in `assert.get` is number not object.

So `call=40` and `call.request` is `undefined`.